# Performance discrepancy of for-loop implementation in Python3

Tags: python, performance

I've written the following code to rotate a looped (i.e., `tail.next = head`) linked list to the right by k:

```py
def rotate_by_k(head, length, k):
    shifts = length - k % length - 1
    new_tail = head
    for _ in range(shifts):
        new_tail = new_tail.next
    new_head = new_tail.next
    new_tail.next = None
    return new_head
```

But after changing the first line as well as the for-loop, I got a performance boost (in runtime, from 43ms to 34ms).

```py
def rotate_by_k(head, length, k):
    k = k % length 
    new_tail = head
    for _ in range(length - k - 1):
        new_tail = new_tail.next
    new_head = new_tail.next
    new_tail.next = None
    return new_head
```

Despite the code is run on LeetCode server, where runtimes are rather inconsistent, but this performance boost seems consistent after several attempts. So I'm wondering what might be the cause of this performance discrepancy.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that can be used to profile those two functions?

Comment: @Brian Thanks for bringing this up! I wrote down a script to test the two functions on my local machine using different examples. It appears that the runtimes are quite random. It's hard to conclude which function is faster. So I hypothesize that there isn't any discrepancy at all, and my question is ill-posed.